# How can I use parallel for in page load?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have few connections like this:

```
try
{
OleDbConnection con1;
using (con1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=db1:1521;Persist Security Info=True;Password=password;User ID=username"))
{
    con1.Open();
    v1 = 1;
    con1.Close();
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
v1 = 0;
}

try
{
OleDbConnection con2;
using (con2 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=db2:1521;Persist Security Info=True;Password=password;User ID=username"))
{
    con2.Open();
    v2 = 1;
    con2.Close();
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
v2 = 0;
}
```

In page_load and working in order. I need parallel run this connections. How can I do that?

Comment: use 2 x Task.Run, 1 for con1 and 2 for con2

Comment: (Off topic) Note that there are also Oracle-specific Connection classes (etc), that may offer more/better functionality, compared to generic OleDb classes.

Comment: @phe: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **C# 6** and **.NET 4.5** you can use the **TPL** with **async** and the code looks even cleaner:

```
static void Main()
{
    var v1Task = Connect();
    var v2Task = Connect();

    var results = Task.WhenAll(v1Task, v2Task);

    var v1 = results.Result[0];
    var v2 = results.Result[1];
}

static async Task<int> Connect()
{
    int v;

    try
    {
        using (var con2 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=db2:1521;Persist Security Info=True;Password=password;User ID=username"))
        {
            await con2.OpenAsync();
            v = 1;
            con2.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        v = 0;
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: +1 I was going to reply with EXACTLY the same code. Only my variables have different names. A strong indication that this is "the way" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Start con1 and con2 asynchronously and wait until both tasks are finished

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=db1:1521;Persist Security Info=True;Password=password;User ID=username"))
        {
            con1.Open();
            v1 = 1;
            con1.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        v1 = 0;
    }
});
var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=db2:1521;Persist Security Info=True;Password=password;User ID=username"))
        {
            con2.Open();
            v2 = 1;
            con2.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        v2 = 0;
    }
});

// If you need to wait until task1 and task2 finished, then use this:
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(task1);
tasks.Add(task2);
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using parallel.for:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();
        string[] connStrings = new string[]{"connstring1", "connstring2"};
        Parallel.For(0, connStrings.Length, (i) => {
            results[connStrings[i]] = TryToConnectToDatabase(connStrings[i]);
        });
    }

    static int TryToConnectToDatabase(string connstr)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection con1;
            using (con1 = new OleDbConnection(connstr))
            {
                con1.Open();
                con1.Close();
                return 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```